# Python3 executing Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I need to execute a Javascript function from Python 3 (pass a few variables into it's environment and collect the result). I found pyv8 and python-spidermonkey, but neither supports Python 3.

Is there a library for that job?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to expose the JS function as a "web service method"? Probably a lot cleaner than "embedding a JS exe env" => expose your functions as NodeJS HTTP endpoints.

Comment: ok, this is a total hack, but you could use mongodb to do that. it supports native js evaluation and its bindings are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

What you can always do:

- Install Node.Js binaries on the server-side
- Write a script as standalone .js file
- Pass input as command-line arguments, pipes (stdin) or files
- Execute the script using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess)
- Collect the result from a named pipe or file output

.js scripts can be executed in similar fashion as .sh and .py scripts.